# Zendserver configaration

Tags: php, zend-framework

Do I need to update my host file and apache httpd.conf files manually whenever I create a new zf project using command.

For ex: if my new project is zendi.

**in host file:**

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   zendi
```

**in httpd.conf:**

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1>
    DocumentRoot "C:\wamp\www\zendi\public"
    ServerName zendi
    ErrorLog "C:\wamp\logs\apache_error.log"
    <Directory "C:\wamp\www\zendi\public" >
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>  
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: You know how to spell "Zend", could you take some time and care to spell at least that correctly, please?

Comment: Damien Pirsy: Sorry.. Typing mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP 5.4, then you can use the built-in web server, and you don't even need Apache.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php

Comment: No I'm using 5.3version.. So that means I have to do it manually right.. Thank you btw.

Comment: Well, it means you can't use the built-in web server :-)  I don't know the latest versions of ZF but in Symfony it detects your web root automatically, so you can just have one folder containing all of your projects, and access them by a subdirectory, like `http://localhost/somesite.com/`

Comment: Yah!! I would do that.. :D Thanx alot!! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use virtual host for your newly created zf application then the answer is YES you need to configure it manually command line project creation doesn't configure it for you. But if you don't need to have virtual server for every application you create then you can skip the process and go with direct url:

> localhost/zendi/public

(But it is often considered good practice to have virtual hosts configured for the projects that you'll be working for a while)